# How should I batch make thumbnails with the original images located in multiple subdirectories?

Tags: linux, image, terminal

I have the original images in a directory structure that looks like this:

```
./Alabama/1.jpg
./Alabama/2.jpg
./Alabama/3.jpg
./Alaska/1.jpg
...the rest of the states...
```

I wanted to convert all of the original images into thumbnails so I can display them on a website.  After a bit of digging / experimenting, I came up with the following Linux command:

```
find . -type f -iname '*.jpg' | sed -e 's/\.jpg$//' | xargs -I Y convert Y.jpg -thumbnail x100\> Y-small.jpg
```

It recursively finds all the jpg images in my subdirectories, removes the file type (.jpg) from them so I can rename them later, then makes them into a thumbnail and renames them with '-small' appended before the file type.

It worked for my purposes, but its a tad complicated and it isn't very robust.  For example, I'm not sure how I would insert 'small-' at the beginning of the file's name (so `./Alabama/small-1.jpg`).

Questions:

1. Is there a better, more robust way of creating thumbnails from images that are located in multiple subdirectories?
2. Can I make the existing command more robust (for example, but using `sed` to rename the outputted thumbnail before it is saved- basically modify the Y-small.jpg part).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to build up such a complicated construct. Make small blocks first, then connect.

I have decided to **not** insert `-small` in the middle of the filename. it makes everything more complicated. Better to use a prefix (simpler code, and also easier to derive the original filename from the thumb) which can either be a `thumbsDir/` or a `thumbsPrefix-`.

```
#!/bin/sh

make_thumbnail() {
    pic=$1
    thumb=$(dirname "$1")/thumb-$(basename "$1")
    convert "$pic" -thumbnail x100 "$thumb"
}

# Now we need a way to call make_thumbnail on each file.
# The easiest robust way is to restrict on files at level 2, and glob those
# with */*.jpg
# (we could also glob levels 2 and 3 with two globs: */*.jpg */*/*.jpg)

for pic in */*.jpg
do
    make_thumbnail "$pic"
done
```